# Android - Increase speed of encryption

Tags: android, image, encryption, image-processing

I am not sure if this is possible...i have code within my application which encrypts images...

```
Cipher cipher;
SecretKey key;
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
DesEncrypter() {
   byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,
      0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17 };
   key = new SecretKeySpec(iv, "AES");
   try {
     cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
     cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);          
   } 
   catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {}
 }        

public void encrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    try {
      out = new CipherOutputStream(out, cipher);
      int numRead = 0;
      while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
          out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
      }
      out.close();
    }
```

Every time i encrypt or decrypt an image (which my application does alot) it takes a very long time, any tips on how to increase the process so users have a better experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to trade a bit of security for speed, than you could only encrypt specific parts of the picture: for example first 100 bytes out of every 1000 bytes of datastream.

Also, use AsyncTask, as @Estel suggested, so that your UI won't suffer delays.

Comment: Any links showing examples of how i could implement an AsyncTask?

Comment: can you suggest how to encrypt first 100 bytes of every 1000 bytes ? can you post some code here ?

Answer (score 2):

You might pick a different AES mode, something different from ECB. Not only for speed but for doing a [better job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) than ECB of encrypting images.

Comment: Other modes are superior to ECB for many things but they aren't any faster.

Comment: It can depend on the framework, for example: http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html

Answer (score 1):

My best suggestion would be to increase the size of the buffer

Answer (score 1):

If your user experience is suffering, have you put the this encryption algorithm in an ASyncTask? For expensive operations like this, an ASyncTask is necessary to keep the user experience smooth.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use bigger buffers
2. Use AsyncTask. You can even show user progress in the notification bar, that should keep him happy.
3. Use NDK to write native code for encryption